# Alien consciousness 'finds' human soldier, soldier becomes President

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to identify a short-story, definitely written before the 1980's.

The story was told in four parts;

**1.** There was a biography-like introduction which lays out the story; the bizarrely meteoric rise of a private soldier to President of Earth and his similarly mysterious assassination.

---

**2.** An alien consciousness is drifting around, flicking through various universes. It passes a universe of matter (ours, obviously) and is surprised to find intelligence. This confuses it as it usually only finds intelligent life in planes of energy. It drifts towards a life-form and is *sucked* into the head of a xenophobic American private soldier fighting in a future war against a Chinese invasion of the US. There's an incident where the soldier walks through a gas grenade without breathing apparatus. The Chinese (who're completely astounded by this) fire on the soldier and finally dispatch him with a grenade.

**3.** The entity, not realising that its host is a dying man (killed and dismembered by a grenade) begins to rebuild him out of dirt and individual atoms, eventually dragging itself out of the ground several years after the war has ended. He encounters a policeman and tells him to "*Throw down your badge but keep your gun. You'll need it where we're going*". The policeman, strangely mesmerised by his charisma, does as he's told.

**4.** Cut to a few years later. A group of insurgents/terrorists are watching the soldier (now President) give a speech. They have a psychic child who indicates that there's a second entity inside the President's head. The psychic shouts "Free!" and the entity returns to its own plane of existence. The soldier disappears in a puff of smoke.

Comment: So there is a President of Earth and there is a US that it at war with China? Or is this President of Earth a new position after the war is over?

Comment: I'm not sure. From memory, the US repulse the Chinese invasion. The post-war segment is solely set in the US so he could have been the US President.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Entity Trap](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61753)" by Fredric Brown.

As described by [another searcher](http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/Science_Fiction/Energy_creature_becomes_trapped_in_dead_soldiers_head/abesleuthcom/28791.1?mode=simple&redirCnt=1&u=473261078&nav=messages)

> An energy creature becomes trapped in the head of a soldier as he dies
> (the only remaining part of the soldier is his head after an explosion
> and the energy creature is "sucked in" and trapped by the matter when
> the soldier dies.) it is controlled by the memories of the dead
> soldier. Through the powers of the energy creature, it rebuilds the
> body and eventually becomes president of the united states but has a
> ultra nationalistic view of the world because of the memories within
> the head. Two other energy creatures eventually find the trapped
> energy creature and help free it. The only thing left of the man when
> the energy creature is freed is his head which falls on a table.
>
> I have a feeling the Soldiers name was John Dix or similar. I read it
> in a book of short science fiction stories.

Comment: The soldier's name was indeed John Dix. ["From These Ashes"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81960) is another title for the same story, which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Amazing_Stories_v24n08_1950-08_LennyS-EXciter#page/n45/mode/2up).